# Bootstrap4 Accordion won't stay open

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

All-

I had this working on Bootstrap 3.7.7. Updated to 4.1.1. and my accordions broke. They won't stay open. The link works and the card looks like it will open and then closes itself or disappears. Like I said everything was working this morning on 3.7.7 but wanted to get to 4.1.1 before I moved forward anymore.

```html
    <!--Accordion wrapper-->
    <div class="accordion accordion-4" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="HeadingInternet">
                <a class="card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapse10" href="#collapse10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapse10">
                    <h3 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
                        Internet<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down pull-right" href="#collapse10"></span>
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse10" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" aria-labelledby="#HeadingInternet">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
                        non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch
                        3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                        shoreditch et.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                        sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
                        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
                        accusamus labore.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Accordion card -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTV">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse11" data-parent="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse11">
                    <h3 class="mb-0 black-text text-left font-weight-bold">TV<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down pull-right" href="#collapse11"></span></h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse11" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTV" data-parent="#accordion1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
                        non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch
                        3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                        shoreditch et.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                        sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
                        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
                        accusamus labore.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Accordion card -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingPhone">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse12">
                    <h3 class="mb-0 black-text text-left font-weight-bold">Phone<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down pull-right" href="#collapse12"></span></h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse12" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading12" data-parent="#accordion1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
                        non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch
                        3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                        shoreditch et.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                        sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
                        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
                        accusamus labore.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your example is working on bootstrap 4: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/84386/

Comment: You're right @DavidLiang . I had updated the CDN for CSS but not the JS file. Got it now. Thanks!